# Is there only one continuous-everywhere non-differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm reading Landau's: *Differential and Integral Calculus*. On theorem 100, he states: There is an everywhere-continuous nowhere-differentiable function. I've read somewhere that these patological functions are way more common than continuous functions, and that actually, continuous functions are the exceptions. I don't remember where I read it though nor if I read it wrong.

So I'm confused because he says that there is one, although he does not says that there exists only one.

**EDIT**: I know about the existence of the Weierstrass Function, and the idea mentioned below by *regret*, but I'm looking for something less trivial and that is not a byproduct of Weierstrass function.

Comment: If the function $f$ is continuous and non-differentiable everywhere, $f+C$ is as well.

Comment: "There is an" does not mean "There is a unique".

Comment: Weierstrass function is far from being an isolated example: although it is "pathological", it is also "typical" of continuous functions : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: @user1537366 Yes. And "*although he does not says that there exists only one*" means that I know that. If there is only one, the proposition *there is one[...]* is valid, If there is more than one, it's also valid.

Comment: OK, sorry I didn't read very carefully. I'd have deleted my comment if it was not referenced in the answer below... but I thought you should have seen so many instances of "there is ..." which do not imply that there is only one?

Comment: @user1537366: I think you are fine in leaving the comment there. The OP may know this, but someone else stumbling upon the question may not.

Comment: With probability 1, any realization of a [Wiener process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) is such a function.

Comment: @user1537366 Yes, it's normal. The economic system of MSE is driving users to comment/answer without careful reading/thought. People reply to what they see in the question but they don't read the text. In the anxious movement to get more reputation points they *shoot* something almost instinctively.

Comment: Hint: with the help of baire theorem, Nowhere differential functions are dense in space of continous functions on $\mathbb R$ with supperimum norm.

Comment: @Vÿska You are probably quite right, but I don't usually do that (I really thought I read the whole question), and comments don't get reputation points.

Comment: Re: "The economic system of MSE is driving users to comment/answer without careful reading/thought." You don't think at least part of the reason is that you asked a clear, precise, and unambiguous question in the title that is not the question you actually wanted the answer to?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I assume I'm arbitrarily stupid too. But I've already made some questions in which it was clear that the answerer read only the question, not the text. And it was precisely what [user1537366 assumed here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088261/is-there-only-one-continuous-everywhere-non-differentiable-funtion?noredirect=1#comment2217234_1088261).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main result on the topic is the Banach-Mazurkiewicz theorem, that states:

*the set of all nowhere differentiable functions on [a,b] is of the second category (in the sense of Baire's category theorem) in C[a,b]*.

Informally and intuitively this means that there are uncountable infinitely many functions that are everywhere continuous but everywhere not differentiable. We can give e more precise meaning to this informal statement in a topological or measure theory sense as sketched in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).
You can find a proof in the thesis [cited](http://epubl.luth.se/1402-1617/2003/320/LTU-EX-03320-SE.pdf) in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**.

As [user1537366  pointed out in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088261/is-there-only-one-continuous-everywhere-non-differentiable-funtion#comment2217011_1088261), "there exists" does not mean "there exists only one". The latter is so different from the former, it has its own symbol. While $\exists$ is used to mean "there exists", $\exists!$ or $\exists_1$ can be used to mean "there exists only one". "There exists" or $\exists$ means that there exists **at least** one, possibly more, or perhaps even infinitely many.

Just as a simple way to demonstrate that the answer is no: For an everywhere-continuous nowhere-differentiable function $f$, there are infinitely many $f+C$ with the same qualities.

Here is a proof of this. By continuity,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)&=f(x_0)\\
(\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x))+C&=f(x_0)+C\\
(\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)+C)&=f(x_0)+C\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore $f+C$ is continuous. Finally, take a look at the definition for derivative:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Checking this for $f+C$, it is clear that $f+C$ is differentiable if and only if $f$ is. Since $f$ is not, $f+C$ is not.

Based on this, you might think the set of everywhere-continuous nowhere-differentiable functions contains only all $f+C$ for some single function $f$. This is not the case, however. For example, [the Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) has a couple of parameters you can set.

Comment: Yes but thinking $f+C$ seems too trivial. I was thinking about something non-trivial.

Comment: It's like: "Hey, I can survive if someone drop a number of atomic bombs in me. I can survive precisely if people drop $0$ atomic bombs in me."

Comment: @Vÿska: I think you are right, it is a little trivial. However, your question did not specify what is or is not considered trivial, or if triviality should even be considered. $f$ and $f+1$ are two distinct functions, they are not equal, therefore the existence of $1$ implies the existence of infinitely many. If you want an explicit, "nontrivial" example of a set of everywhere-continuous nowhere-differentiable functions, the final link in my answer contains one.

Comment: Yes. I know Weierstrass function, but even tweaking the parameters, the resultant functions would still be a byproduct of Weierstrass function. I want to know if there is something that is not a byproduct of it.

Comment: @Vÿska: Here is such a function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlancmangeFunction.html

Comment: for an exhaustive treatment of the topic see:http://epubl.luth.se/1402-1617/2003/320/LTU-EX-03320-SE.pdf

Comment: @Vÿska: My point was, to get more specific answers, ask a more specific question. If you had already said these things in the question, you would not have to clarify later in the comments.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Does this thesis really speaks about it? The title is Continuous Nowhere Differentiable Functions. I asked about everywhere-continuous nowhere-differentiable functions.

Comment: @Vÿska: Heh, good call. The title seriously needs some punctuation. I believe they mean **Continuous, Nowhere Differentiable** rather than **Continuous Nowhere, Differentiable**, as the latter type of function does not exist and the abstract indicates the former.

Comment: @regret I wouldn't be so sure. I thought that division by zero wasn't possible until I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) and I also found [this](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/red+herring+principle) about naming mathematical objects.

Comment: @Vÿska: I suppose you are right, but I think the abstract of the text confirms my suspicions.

Comment: @regret Yes. But mathematics is like a set of doors, if you open one, there are infinite other doors. And then if you choose one of these new doors, sometimes you find a connection between two doors, sometimes you open more and more doors. Who knows what those guys at Princeton's Institute for Advanced Study are thinking by now?